# What is the origin of "dipshit"

Tags: etymology

Where does the word "dipshit" originate from?

It seems to be both a noun and adjective.

As a noun

> What a dipshit!

As an adjective

> You dipshit!

Comment: Hi Aaron. Stack Exchange is not really the place to ask just any question: We require evidence of research before any question may be answered. You can read more about this policy in [Are Some Questions Too Simple](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) and our other policies in the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/). Did you check a commonly available online resource, like [Oxford Living Dictionaries](http://tinyurl.com/jlg383l) or [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://tinyurl.com/h87xapo) before asking us? If so, what is your cause of doubt?

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know, it's also a noun in your example of an adjective.

Anyway, this is what [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dipshit) has to say about it:

> "stupid person, eccentric person," 1920s slang, perhaps a back-formation from [dippy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dippy&allowed_in_frame=0). "*Dipshit* is an emphatic form of dip (2); *dipstick* may be a euphemism or may reflect putative *dipstick* 'penis' " [DAS].